# What is the difference between loading js in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, blazor, maps, blazor-server-side

I'm making a Yandex maps component in Blazor Server. I load the script through a line in _Host.cshtml:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=abc"></script>
```

Everything works. Now I'm trying to load the same line in the component (removing it from the Host):

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=abc");
```

It loads, and immediately gives an error:
[image]
[image]
It turns out that the script is loaded in a different way, but what is the difference? And how to load the script from the code in the same way as it is loaded from the Host?